# Boolean value doesn't change

Tags: html, angular, typescript, boolean, primeng

I have a problem. After searching for hours I cannot find an explanation for this. I want to display a modal (from [primeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)) and show it when the user clicks a button. This button calls (with an id) to my API REST and brings information, very simple. I receive the information, but when the modal should show, this doesn't happen.

> map.component.ts

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  public alteraciones: any[];
  public alteracion: any = {};
  display: boolean = false;
/*...*/
generateData(map: L.map) {
    const data: any[] = [];
    let marker: any;

    L.geoJson(this.alteraciones, {
      pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
        marker = L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: this.getIconMarker(feature.properties.tipo_alteracion)
        });

        marker.on('click', (e) => {
          this.getInfoAlteracion(feature.properties.id_alteracion); // <==
        });
        data.push(marker);
      }
    });    
/*...*/

  }
/**...**/
getInfoAlteracion(id_alteracion: string) {
    this.mapService.getInfoAlteracion(id_alteracion).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.alteracion = result;
        console.log(this.alteracion); // < == Information OK
        this.display = true; // <== this variable should change but doesn't
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

}
```

> map.component.html

```
<p-dialog header="Info" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="500" [responsive]="true">
<!--some code-->
  <p-footer>
    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="display=false" label="Cerrar"></button>
  </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

However, when I recompile or when I turn off the server, the value of the display variable changes, and it shows me the modal. I cannot find an explanation, any idea?

**EDIT**

Posible conflicts:

@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet: 3.0.2

@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster: 1.0.0

**EDIT 2**

I also added a new marker with a new variable to change but doesn't work too. At this point, I think (and I'm 90% sure) that it's a problem of communication between `component.ts` and `component.html`.

Comment: Try: `[visible]="display"` (one-way binding).

Comment: No, it doesn't work either :/

Comment: If you put `console.log("display", this.display)` after setting `this.display = true;`, do you see the correct value? And if you put `Display: {{ display }}` somewhere in your template (not in the modal), is the value correct?

Comment: try: `[attr.visible]="display"`

Comment: both `console.log` and `{{display}}` show 'false' when I reassign the variable. Only when I recompile or turn off the server, just before everything stops, the value change to 'true'

Comment: `[attr.visible]` does not work either. It seems that the HTML does not connect well with the attribute of the component because (performing the test again),` console.log` shows the change (false -> true) but `{{display}}` in the HTML (outside the modal), don't change

Comment: Do you use `ChangeDetectionStategy.OnPush` in your application?

Comment: I try it but it fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem.Thanks to this [link](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/issues/118), I realized that it was a problem of compatibility between libraries. Leaflet event handlers run outside of Angular's zone, where changes to input bound fields will not be detected automatically. To ensure my changes are detected and applied, I need to make those changed inside of Angular's zone. Adding this to the code, finally, all works:

```
constructor(private mapService: MapService, private zone: NgZone) { }

 marker.on('click', (e) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.getInfoAlteracion(feature.properties.id_alteracion);
          });
        });
        data.push(marker);
      }
```

Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make that boolean display property public !

Comment: I tried it before publishing this question, doesn't work :(

Comment: The implementation seems fine and as you said that the value is changing right before the server stops than I think there must be a problem either with your project setup or something with the API fetching end like the subscriber not resolving the way it supposed to do. You need further debugging from these two aspects.